# Hole in Outside Brick House Repair

Tags: repair, brick, hole-repair

anyone have any idea how to fix this? I had a plumber chip it away cause of an old  tap that burst and replaced the pipe inside and tap. Attached are photos for reference. Would it be OK to just use brick mortar to fix this?

Before
[image]

After
[image]

Comment: No need for me to add another answer  saying the same thing about the mortar fix, but I would isolate the pipe from the mortar mix, especially if the supply pipe is copper by wrapping the pipe in something like a thin closed cell foam that will not hold water. If done neatly and stick a little out of the repair, the foam can be trimmed back after the mortar cures and apply a neat line of exterior grade caulk over the foam. I would also try to keep the dark lines of original mortar visible so the new mortar may not be so noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

Brick mortar would be fine. I would start by drying the area and cleaning it up. Be sure there are no leaks, It needs to stay dry otherwise you will have mold and other problems. You may have to place something in the back of the hole to keep the brick mortar from falling down the back side. Then fill the hole with fresh brick mortar and trowel the surface smooth. If you do not have anything else to patch you can get one of the already made brick mortar from your favorite box store.

Comment: many thanks for your feedback. Its going to be tricky to keep the mortar from falling through the backside without something there to hold in place. I'm sure it won't be too bad if a little mortar fell in the backside?

Comment: Depends a lot on what's back there, @sk3ptic. If you can get to the back side of this wall, just put a couple of layers of duck tape on the inside to hold the mortar in place and don't push _too_ hard. That should keep the mortar in the hole until it's set, then you can peel the tape from the inside or leave it as a mystery for the next person.

Answer (score 0):

the best fix would be to replace the whole brick but that will be tricky.  patching the hole with mortar is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a suitable UV-resistant expanding foam to fill such a hole. When the foam expands, it may fill places that you can't reach. Once it dries, it is generally easy to trim the excess with a knife. And, unlike mortar, it won't crack or chip away.